# Paypal Recurring payement with trial period

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payment

I set up recurring payement within my website using your payum bundle.

PleaseI have a question.  I defined a **trial period ( 1 month )** ( see screenshot into the attachement below ).

So, the **next payment due** will be the same like the **profile start date** or it will be **after one month** ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stDLm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be 1 month after creating recurring.

Comment: Yes, i think that "next payment due"  is defined at same day like profile start date and it will be postponed after a month by paypal

Comment: After creating a profile, PayPal automatically queues payments based on the billing start date, billing frequency, and billing amount. Payments reoccur until the profile expires, there are too many failed payments to continue, or you cancel the profile